# Android change of ActionBar tab from some width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-tabs

I have one tough question. I am now playing with design of the Android application and I have the problem with way how the tabs are displaying from some width of display. I use ActionBarSherlock library and ViewPager for tabs.

The problem is that I use yellow color for ActionBar, black for tabs and again yellow for tab indicators, but when I look at the application on wider screen or in landscape mode (I guess approximately from width 400dp) I can't see the indicators, because tabs are hiden in action bar and indicator has exactly the same color. Is there som way how to change color of tab indicators from some display width?

I have tried to do it by making of layout-sw400dp/layout.xml, new 9patche's and new styles, but I can't make it work this way and I think now that it is impossible to do it this way. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**
I have solved it in the following way. I have created folders drawable-w400dp and drawable-land (for ancient phones). Only phones where it will probably be displayed in the wrog way are black berry like androids.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Action bar style generator. I used this and my tabs have highlights in both orientations http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ it generates 9patches and XML for you

Comment: I have used exactly this ActionBar style generator, but as I said I have still this problem. I have played with it for a hour now and I was not able to figure out how to solve ma problem. 

I see that I have action bar indicator on wider screens, but the problem is that it has same color as when it is not hiden in ActionBar, but I need different one here.